# Output images linked to an ID from another table

Tags: php, html, phpmyadmin

First of all my page displays a dropdown menu with values retrieved from a database. The dropdown is filled with those values from the database. When a value is selected and a button is pressed, the other checkboxes, textfields, etc. are filled in with the according/linked data. Also all coming from the database. But there are also images linked but are located in another table. But also want to output them like I'm doing with the textfields, checkboxes.

The database:

**Table sigaren**

```
- id
- sigaren_name
```

**Table Images**

```
- id
- product_id
- image
```

**Fetching the ID:**

```
$fetch_id_sigaren_select = mysql_query("SELECT id from sigaren WHERE comm_naam = '" .$select. "'");
$fetch_id_sigaren = mysql_fetch_array($fetch_id_sigaren_select);
$resultaat_fetch_id_sigaren = $fetch_id_sigaren['id'];
```

**The query to select the images is pretty simple:**

```
SELECT afbeelding FROM afbeeldingen WHERE product_id = $resultaat_fetch_id_sigaren
```

**Selecting the image(s):**

```
$afbeelding_select = mysql_query("SELECT afbeelding FROM afbeeldingen WHERE sigaren_id = '" .$fetch_id_sigaren. "'");                   
$kwotering = mysql_fetch_array($afbeelding_select);
$resultaat_afbeelding = $afbeelding['afbeelding'];
```

**Output for the images:**

```
echo '<img src="$resultaat_afbeelding">';
```

**Errors:**

Notice: Array to string conversion in D:\Apps\Xampp\htdocs\el_gusto\degustatieform.php on line 1371

Notice: Undefined variable: afbeelding in D:\Apps\Xampp\htdocs\el_gusto\degustatieform.php on line 1373

So extra information, a product(sigaren) can have more than one image but an image cannot have more products.
So it's possible to have more than one image to be shown.
So probably with a foreach?

Can anyone help?

Kind regards and thank you for taking time to read this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this 
**Selecting the image(s):**

```
$afbeelding_select = mysql_query("SELECT afbeelding FROM afbeeldingen WHERE product_id = " .$resultaat_fetch_id_sigaren);                  
while ($kwotering = mysql_fetch_array($afbeelding_select)) {
    $resultaat_afbeelding = $kwotering['afbeelding'];
    echo "<img src='$resultaat_afbeelding'>";
}
```

Comment: Code

<?php
$afbeelding_select = mysql_query("SELECT afbeelding FROM afbeeldingen WHERE sigaren_id = " .$resultaat_fetch_id_sigaren);                  
        while ($afbeelding = mysql_fetch_array($afbeelding_select)) {
$resultaat_afbeelding = $afbeelding['afbeelding'];
echo "<img src='$resultaat_afbeelding'>";
}
?>

I get the following: 

*���Q��Q��p��k�w�F�M��lb'Jc�2N�0��\�c?;��<���^�V�v�0��N.�U��xؤX/�&��s���m�`U�4[�F�Z�g71������Kˌ�Y��N�RW"9����̨T�G��W��8�������js�%��n�g���hU�,�� ~��2w�

Comment: whatever that is doesn't show up properly on stack overflow. Is it an error or what?

Comment: No not error. I think thats the image but not showing as one but as HTML or something.

Comment: instead of `echo "<img src='$resultaat_afbeelding'>";` change it to `echo $resultaat_afbeelding;` just to see if the results are coorect.

Answer (score 0):

PHP

```
$afbeelding_select = mysql_query("SELECT afbeelding FROM afbeeldingen WHERE sigaren_id = " .$resultaat_fetch_id_sigaren);                  
while ($afbeelding = mysql_fetch_array($afbeelding_select)) 
{
$resultaat_afbeelding = $afbeelding['afbeelding'];
$image = "<img src='data:image;base64,".base64_encode ($resultaat_afbeelding)."'>";
}
```

HTML

```
<?php echo $image; ?>
```

Now I'm only getting one image instead of multiple if he needs to output more than one.

And sometimes I get a tiny image icon that is ripped in the middle: [image]

Comment: I guess I have to convert it into a foreach loop?